# Can't edit a downloaded template from Overleaf on TexMaker

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I have downloaded some templates from Overleaf and I am trying to modify them in TexMaker, but whatever I do (Even delete the whole code) renders no result on the PDF output.

On the other side, when I am editing or writing anything else, rather than a template, everything is OK.

I am using the local PDF viewer and not any external one.

I would be glad to help with more specific information but I have no idea what to post as extra!

Edit: Showing the exact error messages I am getting in the log:
They are appearing at line 188 and there is nowhere a line 188.

Edit 2: After searching and searching I found what the problem was. Code was not running because of the "Todonotes package".

```
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \nointerlineskip \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put (0,\ESO@yof... }

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }

! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \ESO@yoffsetI }

! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ... \ESO@HookIIBG \@empty }}\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put ... }

! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \ESO@yoffsetI }

! LaTeX Error: File `todonotes.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \setlength
```

Comment: You will have an error, which will be reported in the log. show the exact error message as a text block in your question

Comment: also "template" which isn't really a defined term in latex usually refers to some local documentclass file `something.cls` such a file on its own will not make pdf output, you need a sample document that uses it.

Comment: I am trying to find the .cls file but it is nowhere to be found!

Comment: Also, I opened 3 other templates, editing each one, the errors where completely different, yet there was no change to the PDF for the first 2. At the last one everything I did, had an impact on the output, so it seemed to be working correctly, yet it is again full of errors that I cannot understand :'(. Sorry for the troublesome question and mixed up comments, wish I knew how to use TexMaker a bit better!

Comment: If you get _any_  error the pdf is not intended to be usable and thinsg are not working correctly

Comment: I think you have reformatted the errors as the last token on the line should show the undefined command but that is niot the case here. (don't use the summary that the editor shows you, show the text from the actual log file) but I would guess that the error is that \AddToHook is not defined, That command is only in the very latest release if your latex is not dated 2021 you will not have it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your kind help and time dedicated!